# Set own color in theme

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use a special color in ThemeData as primarySwatch. I get an error that I should pass MaterialColor instead of Color.

Can I somehow convert Color (#9b210c) to MaterialColor and use it in primarySwatch?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Default red color looks like, You can do the same

```
static const MaterialColor red = MaterialColor(
    _redPrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFFFEBEE),
      100: Color(0xFFFFCDD2),
      200: Color(0xFFEF9A9A),
      300: Color(0xFFE57373),
      400: Color(0xFFEF5350),
      500: Color(_redPrimaryValue),
      600: Color(0xFFE53935),
      700: Color(0xFFD32F2F),
      800: Color(0xFFC62828),
      900: Color(0xFFB71C1C),
    },
  );
  static const int _redPrimaryValue = 0xFFF44336;
```

Read more about the Color System at [Material.io](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-and-palettes)